# Why does Jasny SSO creates a new session id for each broker?

Tags: php, session, single-sign-on

I've tried to set up Jasny SSO, my server is on A.com, where I've also put a broker for testing. I placed a broker on B.com too, and tried to use it. What I faced is Jasny SSO is creating a new session for each broker, thus SSO is just a basic auth (as each broker has different sessions).

My logs say:

```
[2022-07-19T14:01:26.082699+02:00] sso-server.INFO: Attached broker token to session {"broker":"brokerA","token":"a","session":"a"} []
[2022-07-19T14:01:27.178704+02:00] sso-server.INFO: Attached broker token to session {"broker":"brokerB","token":"b","session":"b"} []
```

But the "session" should be the same in the two lines.

---

I didn't change anything, just put the example files on my servers, and changed the configs (broker names, secrets, domains in the server conf and in broker contructors). I use the same FileCache used in the examples.

Comment: Are these two sites on same server?

Comment: @Justinas No, they are on different ones. Afaik it shouldn't be a problem, that is the spirit of SSO.